# Android app that draws approximate locations of nearby WLANs on map

Tags: android, maps, wifi, openstreetmap

Is there an app that logs the signal strength of public WLANs near me, those that I see in the Wifi Dialog of my Phone,  when I walk around in some area? It should draw the approximate location of the WLAN router on some map, Openstreetmap for instance.

It is pretty easy to do this manually., "in your head" , just by walking, when you see the decibel value showing up, then getting stronger, taking on some maximum, then disappearing again.

I am not so much interested in signal strengths from the cell towers of the Phone Companies.

The wifi location does not need to be *that* accurate, and does not have to be displayed in real-time. Could happen after some specified interval: "start logging WLANs" ...take a walk... "end logging WLANs". Then after the walk , "process log".

There are so many WLAN apps in the Play Store  that I don't know which to choose.

Perhaps this can be accomplished with a completey different service, no idea.

Comment: Maybe [this list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_wardrive) gets you started. WiGLE should be a pretty good match for your needs. (Disclosure: link goes to my Android site)

Comment: Thanks Izzy, I didn't know that what I have asked for was called "[wardriving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardriving)" in hacker jargon. I just realized that WiGLE warns me that Android 9/Pie limits that number of WLAN Scans to 2 per minute.  Still, for a slow walk that's enough for my requirements.

Comment: Another crazy restriction by Google. I hate how they cripple useful functionality with each new Android version, "in the name of security"… If you found what matches your needs, you know you can [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), right? ;)

Comment: Good idea – and thanks! Yes, I'm not a designer. However, to me the size looks OK, while on some other sites I have to use Ctrl + mouse-wheel in both directions. And shorter lines + bigger fonts also means less fitting on the screen, so the "comparison factor" would be massively decreased. I rather leave that to the viewer. And at least in FF, you find "View › Zoom" in the menu, where one should expect it ;)